# Office JS setDataAsync function memory leak

Tags: excel, memory-leaks, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

When using Async functions in the shared API of the office js in Excel 2016 it causes a memory leak, specifically calling `binding.setDataAsnyc` which never releases the data written.( **The leak is in the *internet explorer* process running the addin within excel( it is a 32-bit version one)**).

Example :

```
//1 Miliion row by 10 columns data parsed from a csv usually in chunks
var data = [];
var i,j;
for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    row = [];
    for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
        row.push("data" + i + "" + j);
    }
    data.push(row);
}
var limit = 10000;
var next = function (step) {
    var columnLetter = getExcelColumnName(data[0].length);
    var startRow = step * limit + 1;
    var endRow = start + limit;
    if (data.length < startRow)
        return;
    var values = data.slice(startRow - 1, endRow - 1);
    var range = "A" + startRow + ":" + columnLetter + "" + endRow;
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(range,
        Office.CoercionType.Matrix, { id: "binding" + step },
        function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
                console.log('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
                return;
            }

            Office.select("bindings#binding" + step).setDataAsync(values,
                {
                    coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Matrix
                }, function (asyncResult) {
                    //Memory keeps Increasing on this callback
                    if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                        console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
                        return;
                     }

                     next(step++);
                });
        });
    }

next(0);
```

I tried releasing each binding after the `setDataAsync` but still the memory persists. the only way to reclaim the memory is to reload the addin.

I tried the other way of assigning values to ranges:

```
range.values = values;
```

It doesn't leak but take 3 times as long as `setDataAsync` (approximately 210 seconds for 1M rows by 10 columns) while `setDataAsync` take about 70 seconds but of course leaks and consumes 1.1 GB of memory in that request.

I also tried `table.rows.add(null, values);` but that's got even worse performance.

I tested the same code without `setdataAsync` (calling next right away) and no memory leak occurs.

Did anybody else experience this?
Is there anyway around it to release that memory?
If not is there another way to fill large amount of data in Excel except these 3 methods that is also fast?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a binding does increase memory consumption -- but just calling `setDataAsync` definitely should not (or at least, not by more than you'd expect, or by more than copy-pasting the data into the sheet manually would be).

One thing to clarify: when you say:

> I also tried `table.rows.add(null, values)` but that's even worse performance.

I assume you mean doing the alternate Office 2016-wave-of-APIs syntax, using an `Excel.run(function(context) { ... });`?  I can follow up regarding perf, but I'm curious if the memory leak happens when you use the new API syntax as well.

FWIW, there is an API coming in the near-ish future that will allow you to suspend calculation while setting values -- that should increase performance.  But I do want to see if we can figure out the two issues you're pointing out:  the memory leak on `setDataAsync` and the `range.values` call.

If you can begin by answering the question above (whether the same leak occurs even in `range.values`), it will help narrow down the issue, and then I'll follow up with the team.

Thanks!

Comment: No, `range.values` (inside `Excel.run`) doesn't leak memory but as said is much slower (3x slower) than setDataAsync.

Also I tried calling `releaseByIdAsync` after each `setDataAsync` and still the memory is never released.

Comment: Ok, perfect, thanks for the info.  Let me pass it on to the team to investigate.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any ETA on the new API with improvements to setting values?

Comment: @MahmoudBahaa, the earliest would probably be 3 months from now (simple physics -- the 1.5 ExcelApis just got shipped, and should be out publicly in ~2 months time from being "done"; so since it's not part of that train, it would be something thereafter.  So, though I cannot guarantee anything, something in the 3-6 months range is probably a decent guess).

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is a boolean `window.Excel._RedirectV1APIs` that you can set to `true` that make `setDataAsync` use the new API. It should be set automatically if

`window.Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported("RedirectV1Api")`

return true but somehow that requirement is not set but it works if you set manually

`window.Excel._RedirectV1APIs = true`

yet it is still much slower than native `setDataAsync` but slightly faster than the `range.values` manual approach (160s vs 180s for 1M rows by 10 cols) and don't cause memory leaks.

Also, I found out that the memory leak happens after `window.external.Execute(id, params, callback)` function with id: 71 (`setDataAsnyc`) and on calling the callback from that function so it seems the memory leak somehow happens in/because of external code in Excel itself (although the memory leak is in the internet explorer process though). If you short circuit and just call the callback directly instead of `window.external.Execute` no memory leak happens, but of course, no data is set either.